# Google BigQuery table disappears after a few days

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm streaming data using bigquery, but somehow the table I created will disappear from WebUI while the dataset will remain.

I set up the dataset as never expire, is there any configuration for the table itself?

Comment: I had the same problem when I created the dataset and table with bq command line. 
It defaults table expiration set for one hour unless you specify. I had to change manually on the WebUI or command line

Answer (score 1):

I'd look into Mikhail's suggestion of the table's explicit expiration time.  The tables could also be getting deleted via the tables.delete API, possibly by another user or process.  You could check operations on your table in your project's [audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/audit-logs) and see if something is deleting them.

Comment: I looked the logs but  I didn't find any records related to the table I interested. Not even the create record, T.T  Any thoughts related that?

Answer (score 0):

> is there any configuration for the table itself?

Expiration that is set for dataset is just default expiration for newly created tables
Table itself can be set with expiration using [expirationTime](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables#expirationTime) property

Comment: You mean if we set up the dataset expiration, then the tables in the dataset will share the same expiration? And is that true that just myself or the authenticated user can delete the table doesn't expiration?

Comment: No. tables will not share expiration with dataset. Expiration set on dataset level is called`defaultTableExpirationMs` and once this property is set, all newly-created tables in the dataset will have an expirationTime property set to the creation time plus the value in this property, and changing the value will only affect new tables, not existing ones. When the expirationTime for a given table is reached, that table will be deleted automatically.

Comment: the table that doesn't have expiration (or any table) can be deleted by those users with respective permissions in dataset ACL